# Leafletjs, overriding the max zoom in option

Tags: leaflet

I have a standard leaflet map, for various reasons (high resolution data) I need to zoom in further than the default settings allow, to centimetres.

how do I override this max zoom setting?

My code is currently:

```
<script>


    // Set the projection system using proj4js and proj4leafletjs(not sure this works yet)
    var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:32365',
    '+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
    {
    resolutions: [
      8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128
    ],
    origin: [0, 0]
    })


   // Creating map options
   var mapOptions = {
      center: [38.623162,27.9282893],
      zoom: 10,
      zoomSnap: 0.25
   }

   // Creating a map object
   var map = new L.map('map', mapOptions);

   // Creating a Layer object
   var layer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

   // Adding layer to the map
   map.addLayer(layer);
</script>
```

Comment: Tile Layer `maxZoom` option?

Comment: It seems that the tileLayer restricts zooming, if I disable it I can zoom in infinitely.